# Remove MessageData from repository after successful consumption

Tags: .net, masstransit

I'm passing a lot of data through RabbitMQ and to offload the queues I'm using the Claim Check pattern to store byte blob outside of the queue itself. It works great, but I have a question about cleanup in the `FileSystemMessageDataRepository`. Right now I'm specifying TTL for 7 days - in case of any fatal issues with consumer we wish to have this data ready.

```
// My RabbitMq setup
var messageDataRepository = new FileSystemMessageDataRepository(new DirectoryInfo(massTransitSettings.RabbitMqDataMessageRepositoryPath));
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IMessageDataRepository>(messageDataRepository);
        serviceCollection.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.UsingRabbitMq((context,cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host(massTransitSettings.RabbitMqHost, massTransitSettings.RabbitMqVirtualHost, h => {
                    h.Username(massTransitSettings.RabbitMqUsername);
                    h.Password(massTransitSettings.RabbitMqPassword);
                });

                cfg.UseMessageData(messageDataRepository);

                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });
        });

// Message passing and setting up the TTL
var messageData = await messageDataRepository.PutBytes(bufferToSend, TimeSpan.FromDays(7), cancellationToken);
var payload = new MyPayload(messageData, bytesRead);
await bus.Publish(payload, cancellationToken);
```

The issue i have now is that i don't want `MessageData` of consumed messages to stick around. After successful consumption i would love to just remove that, but so far i cannot find an option for that. `IMessageDataRepository` does not have delete methods and I cannot find any option for this to happen automatically. Does anyone have a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit doesn't do any automatic cleanup for you. With the TTL option, the folders are named by the date/hour, so you should be able to write a simple enough script to nuke everything older than a specific time period.

Comment: While that's totally fair - i think it would be nice to write that out explicitly in the documentation for Claim Check. Because when i read about TTL and I'm using built-in repository my assumption was that the TTL is carried out some way

Comment: Also that TTL for FileSystemMessageDataRepository has resolution only to on hour, setting TTL for 15 minutes is not reflected in the file system path

Comment: You assumed incorrectly. The documentation could make this more clear, you're welcome to submit a PR. And 15 minutes is too granular. Clean up the folders are a day or two, doesn't even have to be on the hour.

Comment: We are processing 12 GB per hour so i had to just implement custom MessageDataRepository, but works great now